# Align ToC pagenumber with top line

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, page-numbering

I need to align the pagenumber with the top line of a multi-line entry in a ToC. This figure should illustrate the issue:

[image: The "2" needs to be moved to the top line]

Here is the relevant code from the style file:

```
\titlecontents{figure}[0pt]
{\normalfont\mdseries\singlespacing\hangindent=2em}    
{\figuretitlename ~ \thecontentslabel : \hspace{.25em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{}\contentspage}
```

If it helps, here are additional links:

- The style file (linked to the line above): https://github.com/cci-grads/uncc-thesis-latex/blob/master/packages/unccspecs.sty#L575
- The entire repo: https://github.com/cci-grads/uncc-thesis-latex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.