# TOC: Page number align at TOP rather than bottom

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Simply, how would I align the page number at the top of a really long TOC entry?[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\newcommand{\listdefinitionname}{My list of definitions}
\newlistof{definition}{def}{\listdefinitionname}
\newcommand{\definition}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{definition}%
  \par\noindent\textbf{The Definition~\thedefinition. #1}%
  \addcontentsline{def}{definition}
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\thedefinition}#1}\par%
}
\makeatletter
\preto\chapter{\addtocontents{def}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofdefinition
\chapter{A chapter}
\definition{Some really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long definition}
\definition{Some definition}
\definition{Some definition}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Related but without an answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135640. Related with an answer of **egreg**: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250876

Comment: Neither work actually. They cause the page numbers to be misaligned on the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Following Dr. Manual Kuehner's comment you can adapt [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250901/9057) from [Table of contents alignment problem with multi-line `\pbox` in `\includepdf`'s `addtotoc`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250876/table-of-contents-alignment-problem-with-multi-line-pbox-in-inlcudepdf-addtoto):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\vwdef}[1]{%
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\@pnumwidth-\cftdefinitionnumwidth}\strut#1\unskip\nobreak\strut\par
  \end{varwidth}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\listdefinitionname}{My list of definitions}
\newlistof{definition}{def}{\listdefinitionname}
\newcommand{\definition}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{definition}%
  \par\noindent\textbf{The Definition~\thedefinition. #1}%
  \addcontentsline{def}{definition}
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\thedefinition}\vwdef{#1}}\par%
}
\setlength{\cftdefinitionnumwidth}{2em}

\xpretocmd\chapter{\addtocontents{def}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}{}{}%

\begin{document}

\listofdefinition
\chapter{A chapter}
\definition{Some really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long definition}
\definition{Some definition}
\definition{Some definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]